# How can I tell how many records have been entered in the table in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I designed a comment system for my site. When the post on my site has never been commented on, I want to show them a message like make the first comment. And I also want to print how many comments have been posted on the post. How can I do this with php?

Comment: There's a `COUNT` function in MySQL that returns the number of rows that match whatever criteria you've specified in the query. Have you tried it?

Comment: Why not write some code to achieve that? Without knowing anything about the current state of your application, it's impossible to provide help

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question I am going to assume that you are asking about the database query and that you have a database containing one table named **post** and one table named **comment** where each post can have multiple comments and each comment belong to one post only.

With these conditions in place you could find the number of comments for a post using this query :

`select count(*) from comment where post_id = REPLACE_ME`